# ListView Sorting in Android

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview, baseadapter, android-json

I am binding a `ListView` from `JSONArray`. There is a string distance in it. I just want the list item having the minimum distance must appear as first item in `ListView` and having maximum distance at last list item. Here is my Adapter.

```
public class NearByDockITAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
int loader;


public NearByDockITAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
 activity = a;
 data = d;
 inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
 return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
 return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
 return position;
}

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 View vi = convertView;

 if (convertView == null)
  vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item_layout, null);
  TextView addressTextView = (TextView) vi
   .findViewById(R.id.dockitaddresstext); // Address
 HashMap<String, String> events = new HashMap<String, String>();
 events = data.get(position);

 String distanceString = events.get(Utility.DISTANCE);
 String dis = distanceString;
 addressTextView.setText("(" + dis + ") " + addressString);

 return vi;

   }
 }
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Long.valueOf(String s).longValue(); to a list and then sort it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
public NearByDockITAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
 activity = a;
Collections.sort(d, new Comparator<HashMap<String,String>>() {
    public int compare(HashMap<String,String> a, HashMap<String,String> b) {
        String distanceString1 = a.get(Utility.DISTANCE);
        String distanceString2 = b.get(Utility.DISTANCE);
        return compareDist(distanceString1,distanceString2);
    }
    private int compareDist(String distanceString1,String distanceString2) {
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(distanceString1);
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(distanceString2);
        return i1 - i2;
    }
});
 data = d;
 inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

haven't tested it, but i think it should work.

Comment: You should replace the constructor with this one and complete the imports, and it should work. What else would you like me to add ?

Comment: Thanks...Let Me check

Comment: How can I get events HashMap in constructor as no position is specified there

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Comparator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html)

Here's an example.

```
Comparator<String> StringComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String d1, String d2) {
        Integer i1 = Integer.parseInt(d1);
        Integer i2 = Integer.parseInt(d2);

        // for ascending
        return (int) Math.signum(i1.compareTo(i2));
        // for descending
        // return (int) Math.signum(i1.compareTo(i2)) * -1;
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**

I just found a [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) which provides a great tutorial for sorting Java Objects with examples using [Comparator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html) and [Comparable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

So basically your adapter dataset is a hashMap. The hashmap has to be sorted but as the defination of the class says

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

We wiil use Map instead.

I have changed your code and the type please use this.

```
public class NearByDockITAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
        private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> data;
        private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        int loader;

        public NearByDockITAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
            activity = a;

            data = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
            for (Iterator<HashMap<String, String>> iterator = d.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Map<String, String> map = sortByValues(iterator.next());
                data.add(map);
            }

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;

            if (convertView == null)
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item_layout, null);
            TextView addressTextView = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.dockitaddresstext); // Address
            HashMap<String, String> events = new HashMap<String, String>();
            events = data.get(position);

            String distanceString = events.get(Utility.DISTANCE);
            String dis = distanceString;
            addressTextView.setText("(" + dis + ") " + addressString);

            return vi;

        }
    }

    public static <K extends Comparable, V extends Comparable> Map<K, V> sortByValues(Map<K, V> map) {
        List<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>(map.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<K, V> o1, Entry<K, V> o2) {
                return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
            }
        });

        Map<K, V> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();

        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entries) {
            sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        return sortedMap;
    }
```